# Limit of composite function where the outer function is not continuous

Tags: limits, functions

$\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=g(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)) $

My question is what happens when $g$ is not continuous
say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)= 3$ and

$g(x) =\begin{cases} x\space, x\neq 3 \\
       5\space, x=3\end{cases}$

will $g$ be $3$ or $5$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very much depends on $f$ and $g$. If for example $f(x)=x$, then
$$g(f(x))=\left\{\begin{array}{c} x,\ x\neq 3\\ 5,\ x=3\end{array}\right.$$
Hence you limit may behave like this:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3, x\neq 3}g(f(x))=3.$$
On the other hand if $f(x)=3$ for all $x$, you get $g(f(x))=5$ for all $x$. Hence
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}g(f(x))=5.$$

It is even possible to construct $g$, such that no limit even exists. For example
$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c} \sin(\frac{1}{x}),\ x\neq 0\\ 0,\ x=0\end{array}\right.$$
This $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g(x)$$
does not even exist. If you now set $f(x)=x$ your composite function does not have a limit for $x\rightarrow 0$ as well.

To see that this $g$ is not continuous, just examine the following two sequences:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2\pi k}$$
$$b_k=\frac{1}{2\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Then $g(a_k)=0$ and $g(b_k)=1$, but $a_k,b_k\rightarrow 0$ for $k\rightarrow \infty$